# TOGAF ADM inputs outputs in each phase

Tags: togaf

i start to learn togaf, and try to use adm on small enterprise. ADM say that in each phase should be some outputs and inputs. Can i change set and count of outputs and inputs? i think, that i should not make all artefacts, but is it really with adm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a big part of TOGAF is "tailoring" (modifying) it to meet your needs. So you most certainly can pick out the parts of the ADM that you most need and create essentially your own "architecture framework" based off TOGAF.

As your company grows, over the years, and increases your "architecture capability", you can add more artifacts and increase the complexity of your process.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you can tailor TOGAF ADM, in fact, we required to consider this in the [TOGAF ADM Preliminary Phase](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/learning/booklets/ea/togaf/preliminary.jsp):

[image: TOGAF ADM Overview]

Tailored Architecture Framework (see [Part IV, 36.2.21 Tailored Architecture Framework](http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf9-doc/arch/chap36.html)), including:

- Tailored architecture method
- Tailored architecture content
  (deliverables and artifacts
- Architecture principles (see Part IV,
  36.2.4 Architecture Principles)
- Configured and deployed tools, including evaluation report if conducted

Answer (score 0):

As part of the Togaf framework, it provides ADM guidelines & techniques. Also there are different capability models for Togaf. In most of the cases, these guidelines resemble the real world scenarios. If not, you can modify it based on your scenario. Only thing to take care is that follow the cycle & guidelines as much as possible.